# Why does my AMD CPU have trouble compiling applications?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, intel

Up to September last year, I had been using my Intel i7-based laptop to create and compile my programs, but unfortunately the graphics card broke and so I built a budget computer based around the AMD 4100 FX processor.

Ever since I have started to use the desktop for compiling, I've had all sorts of issues, the main issue being that my applications were really unstable on Intel platforms.

The latest in this spree of issues is that a certain function in my C++ code was being corrupted, seemingly caused by compiling on an AMD CPU.
To test this, I quickly got hold of an AWS (Amazon Web Services) EC2 micro.t2 server, installed Visual Studio 2008 from Dreamspark, downloaded the source-code and compiled it.
Sure enough, there was no corruption of the function and the DLL produced by the source-code ran perfectly.

I'm using Visual Studio 2008, with the stock compiler, and run Windows 8.1 (AWS EC2 server runs Windows Server 2008 R2).
An example of the code that I am trying to compile is the [Crysis Wars SDK](http://www.crydev.net/downloads.php?view=detail&df_id=4486), and bear in mind that this code always compiled fine on my Intel i7 CPU.

Why does my AMD CPU have so much trouble compiling my C++ applications?
Is there anything that I can do about this, other than continue compiling my applications on an AWS EC2 server, or spending cash on a new Intel-based PC build?

Comment: I would run the latest memtest86+ for a day or so. Enable the multithreading mode. There seems to be a problem with the stability of your hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue really was the AMD CPU; when I switched computers the problem vanished. Last year I built another computer using (a different) FX4100 processor, and I was back to the same problem.

It's either an issue specific to the FX4100, or to all of AMD's 'FX' line of processors.

I'm now using an Xeon and haven't seen this issue since.

Comment: Were you compiling with `-march=native`, on the AMD CPU?  I think you said your code was unstable on Intel after you compiled on AMD.  Did they sometimes crash with SIGILL or something?

Comment: @PeterCordes I have no idea, it was over two years ago. I do remember that it was some game mod code via normal 'out of the box' compilation on Visual Studio.

Answer (score 5):

Your processor or memory may be overheating or deficient. Modern compilers are sophisticated beasts, and if you run one at all, it may be the most complex of all the programs you run on your computer. For this reason the compiler may be the only program that reveals hardware issues.

There is an entry in the GCC FAQ to the effect that if the compiler segfaults, [it](http://www.bitwizard.nl/sig11/) may be your memory that has your problem, and not a bug in GCC. I have been affected by this when I over-clocked a Pentium (it was the 90s) and even memtest didn't diagnose anything wrong (but GCC did). Generating wrong code seems like another possible consequence of bad hardware.

What should you do? Check that you didn't leave a sticker between component and radiator, swap memory sticks out to confirm or rule out that they relate to the problem, get the warranty applied if you can confirm an issue. Good luck.

Comment: Interesting answer. The memory is one single stick of DDR3 1066MHZ, and I bought it in September last year (when I built my AMD-based PC). The CPU itself is cooled using water-cooling (maximum of 36 degrees centigrade on load), and the RAM itself doesn't seem to be overheating.
I'm planning to soon upgrade to 8GB RAM; I might as well test your theory or faulty RAM when I do.

Comment: I also certainly didn't leave any stickers on anything, I'm a pretty experienced computer builder.

Comment: @zyboxinternational could you use an “undervolting” utility to limit the frequency of the processor and see if that affects the problem? These utilities do not have to be used to go out of spec. They can also be used to limit the processor within the bounds set by the maker of the processor.

Comment: The CPU isn't overclocked (at the moment), and currently seems to be operating at 1.45v (which I think is normal). I'll use the official ASRock OC program to undervolt the CPU, and will report back.

Comment: The sticker thing happened to a colleague of mine (again in the nineties) with a computer he bought ready-made. Had trouble for 6 months, finally took the thing apart, discovered piece of paper between processor and radiator.

Comment: @cybermonkey have you managed to detect a reason for this stability issue?